# Embedded Linux Power Failure Issues

Tags: embedded

Many routers run a Linux OS and abrupt power failure can happen. Considering this - how do they handle the possibility of file system corruption caused by a power failure? If they make the system read only, how are you able to change settings?

Comment: I had a power failure two days ago that crashed my home made router, so I'm also interested in the answer!! (In my case it was a HW failure but anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routers and other small linux devices do not use hard drives.

They use different types of RAM:

- DDR RAM as working storage
- ROM for system image (Kernel + OS)
- Non Volatile RAM for Settings (/dev/nvram)

In case of an crash they boot again and reinitialize the OS, so nothing get's lost.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so in case of firmware update, how do you go?